# Create custom ID and Description based on values in multiple other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to auto generate the Fixture ID column and Description Column using several cell values:

[image: example image]

The above image includes the required format for both Fixture Id and Description.

Variables for Fixture ID include:

- Part Descriptor: Widget Thing = "WT"
- Part Length and Strength: 20L = 20" + L strength
- Retainer Dimension: 0.75R - 0.75" Retainer

The Description cell simply converts to longer form text with the variables included.

I'm hoping to avoid filling this in manually, but I'm not familiar enough with excel's functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to understand your full question considering "Widget Thing" and "WT" are not a part of the base data and only found within the columns you want to automate. So assuming everything is a "Widget Thing", a "Retainer", and a "Spring" this formula will get you started:

**Fixture ID**

```
="WT-"&G1:G10&H1:H10&"-"&FIXED(F1:F10,2)&"R"
```

**Description**

```
=G1:G10&""" "&IFS(LEFT(A1:A10,2)="WT","Widget Thing w/ ")&F1:F10&""" Retainer & "&H1:H10&" Spring"
```

Adjust range as desired, add additional IF parameters if needed.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you Kevin, with a couple of minor tweaks this worked well